# trying to generate math questions, comparissons not working

Tags: python

[image: My code]

[image: the output]

can anyone help me? im pretty new to python and im trying to generate 10 files, each with increasingly harder questions. this code is for difficult 2. I dont want the answers in dif. 2 to be negative so whenever i get a second number bigger than the first i swap the two. for some reason some of them still come out with the first number bigger than the second. i added the "its less than" print statments for testing and it will detect the fact that its less than but wont do something about it.

Comment: Please post your code directly and not pictures of it

Comment: sorry, never used styack overflow before

Comment: Understandable! But please review this [ask] before asking another question. Welcome to the community!

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that you're casting your random numbers to a string **before** comparing their mathematical values. You need to compare them as integers then cast them to strings.

Comment: Please avoid answering questions that doesn't meet site's guidelines. This will encourage the askers of these type of questions.

Comment: @Asocia fair point! I will avoid it in the future

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because you are checking for comparison between 2 strings not 2 integers. This will give bad results for this type of program

num1 = str(r.choice(numbers))
num2 = str(r.choice(numbers))

Here you are storing strings and not integers.

and then below this you are checking if num1 <= num2.
Convert them to integers before comparing them and your code should work.

Comment: Please avoid answering questions that doesn't meet site's guidelines. This will encourage the askers of these type of questions.